# Why do only some imported objects show textures in the viewport?

Tags: texturing, import

[image: Without Texurted Solid On]Ok so I'm kind of a noob at blender but I was getting into rendering Characters for people. Sometimes when I import 2 objects in (like a chair and a character) the character doesn't have a texture but the chair has it's texture on, then when I hit "Textured Solid" and it just switches (character has textures, chair doesn't) so I was just asking if someone knew how to fix this.

[image: With Textured Solid On]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/

Comment: There isn't any texture on the chair, it's only solid material color shown on it set up probably in the material properties (if in Blender Internal)